# How to convert this Json body to alamofire params format?

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary

I am doing an alamofire request and converting the body params into swift dictionary but I think i am converting it in a wrong format. Can anyone please suggest me what is the right format of this json body into swift params?

The actual body which I am sending in postman which is giving a correct response:-

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "distance_to_next_route_change": "null",
            "accelerationX": "0.10055954",
            "accelerationY": "-0.0047885496",
            "accelerationZ": "-0.0047885496",
            "drivingState": "DRIVING",
            "latitude": "12.921918",
            "longitude": "77.658917",
            "next_route_coordinate": "null",
            "speed": "33",
            "timeStamp": "1560319632021",
            "tripID": "7090291482_1560319518940",
            "maneuver_list": [],
            "tripState": "null",
            "eventId": "event_tacticurv_id"
        }
    ]
}
```

What i am sending in my alamofire params:-

```
let params = [
            "events": [
                [
                    "distance_to_next_route_change": "null",
                    "accelerationX": "0.10055954",
                    "accelerationY": "-0.0047885496",
                    "accelerationZ": "-0.0047885496",
                    "drivingState": "DRIVING",
                    "latitude": "12.921918",
                    "longitude": "77.658917",
                    "next_route_coordinate": "null",
                    "speed": "33",
                    "timeStamp": "1560319632021",
                    "tripID": "7090291482_1560319518940",
                    "maneuver_list": [],
                    "tripState": "null",
                    "eventId": "event_tacticurv_id"
                ],
                [
                    "distance_to_next_route_change": "null",
                    "accelerationX": "0.10055954",
                    "accelerationY": "-0.0047885496",
                    "accelerationZ": "-0.0047885496",
                    "drivingState": "DRIVING",
                    "latitude": "12.921918",
                    "longitude": "77.658917",
                    "next_route_coordinate": "null",
                    "speed": "33",
                    "timeStamp": "1560319632021",
                    "tripID": "7090291482_1560319518940",
                    "maneuver_list": [],
                    "tripState": "null",
                    "eventId": "event_tacticurv_id"
                ]
            ]
        ]
```

expected respose:

```
{
    "code": "OK",
    "message": "Successfully processed your request",
    "statusCode": 200
}
```

response coming:

```
{
    "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
    "message": "Internal server error occured. Please try again later.",
    "statusCode": 500
}
```

Here is the complete code:-

```
func testApi() {

    let defaultManager: Alamofire.SessionManager = {
        let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
            "asia-east2-sandboxkruzr.cloudfunctions.net": .pinCertificates(
                certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificates(),
                validateCertificateChain: true,
                validateHost: true
            ),
            "35.220.245.158": .disableEvaluation
        ]

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders

        return Alamofire.SessionManager(
            configuration: configuration,
            serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
        )
    }()

    let params = [
        "events": [
            [
                "distance_to_next_route_change": "null",
                "accelerationX": "0.10055954",
                "accelerationY": "-0.0047885496",
                "accelerationZ": "-0.0047885496",
                "drivingState": "DRIVING",
                "latitude": "12.921918",
                "longitude": "77.658917",
                "next_route_coordinate": "null",
                "speed": "33",
                "timeStamp": "1560319632021",
                "tripID": "7090291482_1560319518940",
                "maneuver_list": [],
                "tripState": "null",
                "eventId": "event_tacticurv_id"
            ],
            [
                "distance_to_next_route_change": "null",
                "accelerationX": "0.10055954",
                "accelerationY": "-0.0047885496",
                "accelerationZ": "-0.0047885496",
                "drivingState": "DRIVING",
                "latitude": "12.921918",
                "longitude": "77.658917",
                "next_route_coordinate": "null",
                "speed": "33",
                "timeStamp": "1560319632021",
                "tripID": "7090291482_1560319518940",
                "maneuver_list": [],
                "tripState": "null",
                "eventId": "event_tacticurv_id"
            ]
        ]
    ]

    let header = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1aWQiOiJjMGFhYzBkYy1lZGI5LTQzMzEtYWVjNC0wYmU5NTY3MDQ5M2UifQ.kbKSk5FEu2cWceb9MmZH8wefpyObyjmRM6PRDbJkUW0"
    ]
    defaultManager.request("http://35.220.245.158/gateway/events", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header).responseJSON { (response) in
        let _ = defaultManager
        print("api response is")
        print(response.result.value)
    }
}
```

Comment: can I see your code?

Comment: @masoud I edited the question, you can see my complete code.

Comment: its give me 500 error on postman also.

Comment: I think this problem is not from your side.. contact to backend developer for this problem

Answer (score 1):

The brackets are incorrect in your events they need to be { } to represent an individual event class not [ ] which represents an array. They should look like this.

```
let params = [
            "events": [
                {
                    "distance_to_next_route_change": "null",
                    "accelerationX": "0.10055954",
                    "accelerationY": "-0.0047885496",
                    "accelerationZ": "-0.0047885496",
                    "drivingState": "DRIVING",
                    "latitude": "12.921918",
                    "longitude": "77.658917",
                    "next_route_coordinate": "null",
                    "speed": "33",
                    "timeStamp": "1560319632021",
                    "tripID": "7090291482_1560319518940",
                    "maneuver_list": [],
                    "tripState": "null",
                    "eventId": "event_tacticurv_id"
                },
                {
                    "distance_to_next_route_change": "null",
                    "accelerationX": "0.10055954",
                    "accelerationY": "-0.0047885496",
                    "accelerationZ": "-0.0047885496",
                    "drivingState": "DRIVING",
                    "latitude": "12.921918",
                    "longitude": "77.658917",
                    "next_route_coordinate": "null",
                    "speed": "33",
                    "timeStamp": "1560319632021",
                    "tripID": "7090291482_1560319518940",
                    "maneuver_list": [],
                    "tripState": "null",
                    "eventId": "event_tacticurv_id"
                }
            ]
        ]
```

Comment: its wrong data formatting, I have checked for the same in my Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure, but it seems like the problem is not in a bad json.
The response code is 500, which stands for Internal Server Error, but not 400, Bad Request

I ran your code and it generates

```
{
    "speed": "33",
    "accelerationX": "0.10055954",
    "accelerationY": "-0.0047885496",
    "accelerationZ": "-0.0047885496",
    "distance_to_next_route_change": "null",
    "next_route_coordinate": "null",
    "tripID": "7090291482_1560319518940",
    "maneuver_list": [],
    "tripState": "null",
    "timeStamp": "1560319632021",
    "eventId": "event_tacticurv_id",
    "drivingState": "DRIVING",
    "latitude": "12.921918",
    "longitude": "77.658917",
}
```

To check this by yourself just add

```
let request = defaultManager.request("http...
...
debugPrint(request)
```

This will print out curl representation of your request